# Slow HTTP POST request in php

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I'm trying to POSTing some data (a JSON string) from a php script to a java server (all written by myself) and getting the response back.
I tried the following code:

```
$url="http://localhost:8000/hashmap";
$opts = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => $JSONDATA,'header'=>"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
$st = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents($url, false,$st);
```

Now, this code actually works (I get back as result the right answer), but file_get_contents hangs everytime 20 seconds while being executed (I printed the time before and after the instruction). The operations performed by the server are executed in a small amount of time, and I'm sure it's not normal to wait all this time to get the response.
Am I missing something?

Comment: tbh I cant see or know of anything that will help this and all seems alright in your code, however, one suggestion is, why dont you put all of the code in a function and then call the function when you need it.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: i know, but i would like to avoid using extensions for this project, it should be independent from other libraries

Comment: Use Firebug's Net tab or Chrome's developer tools to see where the pause is occuring. could be at any place in the connect -> send data -> script retrieve data -> process data -> output data -> client receive data -> display data stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Connection: close` and `Content-Length: strlen($JSONDATA)` headers to the `$opts`.

Also, if you want to avoid using extensions, have a look at [this class](http://download.networkm.net/code/class.httprequest.1.3.php.tar.gz) I wrote some time ago to perform HTTP requests using PHP core only. It works on PHP4 (which is why I wrote it) and PHP5, and the only extension it ever requires is OpenSSL, and you only need that if you want to do an HTTPS request. Documented(ish) in comments at the top.

Supports all sorts of stuff - GET, POST, PUT and more, including file uploads, cookies, automatic redirect handling. I have used it quite a lot on a platform I work with regularly that is stuck with PHP/4.3.10 and it works beautifully... Even if I do say so myself...

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! Please, can you explain why it has to be done?

Comment: `Content-Length` tells the server how much data you are sending - if you don't include it, the server doesn't know you have finished sending your data, and wont process a response until a timer mechanism on the server expires - how long this is depends on the server. `Connection: close` tells the server to drop the TCP connection immediately after this request is completed, since HTTP/1.1 supports more than one request over a single TCP session. [Read the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html#Keep-Alive) if your interested.

Comment: I wrote the previuos comment before your edit, and i was asking about the connection:close (seems to work even without strlen($jsondata)). I saw your class, pretty cool mate! thanks, i'll use it

Comment: Sorry, I linked to an old version of my HTTP class, link has been updated to a newer version with a few bugfixes

Answer (score 2):

Badly mis-configured server maybe that doesn't send the right content-size and using HTTP/1.1.

Either fix the server or request the data as HTTP/1.0

Comment: The content size is correct. I'm using httpserver sun api and i checked for the right size of the content. tried both 1.0 and 1.1, but it doesn't affect the behaviour. thanks anyway!